# i cannot create a table , what is the wrong here ? ( Syntax error: Encountered "(" )

Tags: create-table

```
String sql = 

"CREATE TABLE coupon53 (
 id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
 title VARCHAR(25),
 start_date DATE,"+ " end_date DATE,
 amount INT,
 type ENUM ('Food', 'Electric', 'Travelling', 'Entertainment', 'Sport'))";
```

Comment: What kind of database are you trying to create this in, MYSQL, SQL Server?

Comment: `type` might possibly be a reserved word and cannot be a field name (without escaping it), but we don't know since you didn't mention the RDBMS.

Comment: There is not an enum in SQL Server.  You will need to use "check constraint" instead.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c7abe3c1-cd48-4ddf-9ce2-b28d0ffb25f6/enum-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql

Comment: can you help me please using the "check constraint" according to my code above ? please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String sql = "CREATE TABLE coupon40 (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(25), start_date DATE,"
+ " end_date DATE,"
+ "amount INTEGER,  type varchar(20) NOT NULL CHECK (type IN('Food', 'Electric', 'Traveling', 'Entertainment', 'Sport')), "
+ "message VARCHAR(25), price DOUBLE PRECISION, image VARCHAR(25))";
```

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "\', \'" at line 1, column 159.

Comment: See Update answer, I forgot a quote '

Comment: quote & close the bracket in the enum type :)
thank you

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the " + " that you have in your query.  Worked fine when I took that out.  If you are querying from the CLI, just hit enter and keep typing and end with ; when you are ready.

EDIT - sorry, answered before I saw you're using sql - worked fine in MySQL.